# View configuration and Module lazy loading in Zend Framework 2

Tags: configuration, zend-framework2

I have designed a initial module lazy-loading system for a particular goal. In my special case there're a few modules that are needed to decorate forms and entities of the rest of the app.

However most of my members will only require a single one of them that will most likely never update. That is why I do not wish to load all of these modules in every request.

Now that worked like a charm until I required to provide extra view files from these modules. It appears like the module's

> view_manager

config is not it merged into the

> ViewManager

which is why the resolver is not capable to resolve the view file. I am now loading all these modules by default for testing -- it works.

My lazy loading mechanism bases on a

> ModuleManager::loadModule()

call in case it is not it loaded already.

Do you know easy approach to properly inject/merge the config into the ViewManager? Also is this a general problem that possibly also affects other components? Or is it a error?

Thank you in advance!